# ZeroMQ: how to find which port a PAIR socket is using?

Tags: python, zeromq, pyzmq

Is there a way to see which port a ZeroMQ (actually `pyzmq`) port is connected to after connecting?
For example...

```
import zmq
context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.PAIR)
port = socket.bind_to_random_port("tcp://*")
# some other code that might change that binding
actual_port = socket.which_port???()  # (this is what I want)
```

Could not find in documentation or other forums.  Would have helped save me some debugging time!

```

Comment: You can get the underlying FD with `sock.get(zmq.FD)` and then use the standard `getsockname` and `getpeername` functions?

Comment: @o11c This sounds like a good direction but I'm still not sure how to do this?  `pyzmq` seems to be missing the `getsockname`, which would tell the port, or I just can't find it?

Comment: By "standard", I meant it's in the `socket` module. You have to call `socket.fromfd` to get a (internally `dup`'ed, so you don't have to worry about having it closed under you) `socket` object first, which requires passing the family (either `AF_INET` or `AF_INET6` - not sure what zmq defaults to) and type (`SOCK_STREAM` for `tcp://`).

Comment: Hmm following this, `getsockname` and `getpeername` return empty byte-strings?

Comment: The empty string refers to a unix socket that is not part of the filesystem - either a client, or both halves of a `socketpair`.

Answer (score 2):

The **`.bind_to_random_port()`** method will automatically pick a port to bind to and the **return** will contain the port it bound too. The return is an `int`.